# Call Android and iOS methods from Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a requirement in which I need to trigger a variable value when a form is opened in either Android or Apple phone.

So how can I call Android as well as iOS functions from my TypeScript file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Navigator) from Web API.
It contains a `userAgent` property that is a string that delivers information about your OS and device.

```
export class YourComponent {
  private isAndroid(): boolean {
    return /android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
  }

  private isIOS(): boolean {
    return /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent)
  }
}
```